# Как закрепить заголовок DataFrame при экспорте в Excel файл?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

Хочу чтобы заголовок DataFrame был закреплен в Excel файле.

Как я могу этого добится?

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь [параметром `freeze_panes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):

```
df.to_excel(..., freeze_panes=(1,0))
```